# "Object which.column not found" when reading in land-cover dataset with stars (R)

Tags: raster, r, land-cover, stars

I'm not sure where the problem lies--in R, a quirk of the dataset, my own computer?

The dataset in question is a raster dataset of land cover in the United States. It's linked from the MRLC, but for consistency, the specific download that I've used is from here (http://www.cec.org/north-american-environmental-atlas/land-cover-30m-2020/), and is the TIF button at the bottom of the page. Be warned, the download is 3.7gb.

I unzipped the contents of the folder and tried to open them with the `stars` package:

```
landCover <- read_stars('Land Data/usa_land_cover/NA_NALCMS_landcover_2020_30m.tif')
```

at which point it "loads" (via a proxy) in memory. The landCover object instantiates just fine. But when I try to use the proxy that `stars` automatically creates to plot anything (say, `plot(landCover, downsample = 500)`, or specify not to use a proxy, or anything else, I get the following error:

```
Error in read_stars(file_name, RasterIO = rasterio, NA_value = attr(x,  : 
  object 'which.column' not found
```

Running `traceback()` following the error yields the following:

```
8: read_stars(file_name, RasterIO = rasterio, NA_value = attr(x, 
   "NA_value") %||% NA_real_, normalize_path = FALSE, proxy = FALSE, 
   ...)
7: fetch(.x, ..., downsample = downsample)
6: process_call_list(fetch(.x, ..., downsample = downsample), cl, 
       envir = envir, downsample = downsample)
5: st_as_stars.stars_proxy(x, downsample = downsample, ...)
4: st_as_stars(x, downsample = downsample, ...)
3: plot(st_as_stars(x, downsample = downsample, ...), ..., downsample = 0)
2: plot.stars_proxy(landCover, downsample = 500)
1: plot(landCover, downsample = 500)
```

To see if the file was the problem, I opened it in ArcGIS Pro, which successfully displayed the raster. (It said that it'd need to process something on first import, but I didn't take note of what that was.) I tried exporting the open raster to a new .tif file, multiple times, with no luck.

I have also re-downloaded the same dataset, from the same link, on the off chance that the file was corrupted on initial download. It was not. (New file also opens just fine in Arc.)

I'm on Windows 11, running R 4.3.2, `stars` version 0.6-4, and whatever the current (downloaded March 19, 2024) version of ArcGIS Pro is. I'm also open to any suggestions you may have.